# ajax request with url as variable isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two AJAX requests and both are checking if a new rating without awarded points is available.

It doesn't matter if i'm accessing my application via  **localhost:8080**  or **ip-address:8080**, both webservices with mapping **"/nextRating"** are delivering one rating, if available.

I created two global variables, **url1** and **url2**, one for the webservice and one for the site, that should be loaded, if the request has success.

The second request in the function just works fine.

The first doesn't and I just can't figure out why.

```
function checkForNewRating() 
{
  //Extracts the Ip from the url, if accessed via IP:8080/...
    getIp();

    if (ip != null) {
        url1 =  ip.toString() + ":8080/feedback/nextRating";
        url2 = ip.toString() + ":8080/feedback/app";

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url1,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                window.location.assign(url2);
            },
            error: function () 
            {
                console.log(window.location.href);
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/feedback/nextRating",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                window.location.assign("http://localhost:8080/feedback/app");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log(window.location.href);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Requested Code**

```
function getIp() {
  if (href.includes("192.168.")) {
        var startIndex = href.indexOf("1");
        var endIndex = href.indexOf(":8")
        ip = href.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    }
}
```

This function works fine, the url variables are getting set correctly

Comment: what is the vaue of 'ip' variable? where are you assigning it?

Comment: In getIp() at the beginning

Comment: Can you post the `getIp` code?

Comment: CORS. AJAX only works for the same server, unless the server specifically allows requests from another domain by setting the header appropriately.

Comment: Ok. How are you assigning it in getIp? is 'ip' a global variable?

Comment: @ chris g: CORS, of course, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should return the value

```
function getIp() {
  if (href.includes("192.168.")) {
        var startIndex = href.indexOf("1");
        var endIndex = href.indexOf(":8")
        ip = href.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    }
  return ip;
}
```

And in above function get the value like

```
function checkForNewRating() 
{
  //Extracts the Ip from the url, if accessed via IP:8080/...
    var ip = getIp();
```